# Remove the checked list item from the listview dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm dynamcially creating a listview for storing the data. When I clicked on the button then the listview is appended with checkbox's. When I'm selecting the individual checkbox of items in the listview that particular list item has to be deleted from the listview. But when I'm trying to delete the particular item is not deleting.

```
$('#add #input[name="check"]:checkbox').change(function () {
    var chkLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox').length;
    var chkdLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (chkLength == chkdLength) {
        $('#select').attr('checked', true);
        //$('#empty').on('click', function() {
        $('#add input[name="check"]:checkbox:checked').on('click', function () {
            $('#empty').on('click', function () {
                localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr('url'));
                $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('#select').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can first find the ID of row Then find the toggle class on that.

```
  (document).on('click', '.del', function(event) {
      ROW_ID = $(this).closest(".caseRowClick").attr("id");// var caseName_h = $('.caseName_h').val();

      $(".ctrl").toggleClass("togg");


        });
```